# SQL SELECT lan, lon FROM gps_gotaxiking

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table: gps_gotaxiking

`+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| RecordID  | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| CarNo     | varchar(10)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Valid     | varchar(48)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lon       | varchar(13)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lat       | varchar(13)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| angle     | varchar(10)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| speed     | varchar(10)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| CarStatus | varchar(10)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| Time      | datetime            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+`

I want to get all cars' `lat` and `lon` where RecordID is maximum and the `Time` > NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE.
ps: if the RecordED is the max, and it's time would be latest, but i don't want to get all cars' lat and lon in whole time, so i add the condition to filter.

example:
if the system time is 2014/05/13 12:00:00

`+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
| RecordID  |   CarNo   |    lat    |    lon    |        Time         |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
|    9      |     1     |    111    |    111    | 2014/05/13 11:48:05 |
|    8      |     1     |    222    |    222    | 2014/05/13 11:47:30 |
|    7      |     1     |    333    |    333    | 2014/05/13 11:44:20 |
|    3      |     2     |    444    |    444    | 2014/05/13 11:40:59 |
|    2      |     2     |    555    |    555    | 2014/05/13 11:38:00 |
|    1      |     2     |    666    |    666    | 2014/05/13 11:37:21 |
|    15     |     3     |    777    |    777    | 2014/05/13 11:49:17 |
|    14     |     3     |    888    |    888    | 2014/05/13 11:48:16 |
|    13     |     3     |    999    |    999    | 2014/05/13 11:47:15 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+`


In this example, the return should be

`+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
| RecordID  |   CarNo   |    lat    |    lon    |        Time         |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
|    9      |     1     |    111    |    111    | 2014/05/13 11:48:05 |
|    15     |     3     |    777    |    777    | 2014/05/13 11:49:17 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+`

the CarNo2 would not return.
Thanks.

Comment: Use `GROUP BY`. If you don't know how, search.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it joining the table back to itself using `max()`:

```
select g.recordid, g.carno, g.lat, g.long
from gps_gotaxiking g
   join (
      select carno, max(recordid) maxrecordid
      from gps_gotaxiking 
      group by carno
   ) t on g.carno = t.carno and g.recordid = t.maxrecordid
```

Comment: thanks you for your answering, but i edit my question, please help me again.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 Select `RecordID`, `CarNo`, `lat`, `lon` From gps_gotaxiking 
 WHERE RecordID IN (SELECT Max(`RecordID`) `RecordID` FROM gps_gotaxiking
                    group by CarNo )
 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,NOW(),`Time`) > 15
```

[**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a0d6/2)

EDIT:

```
   WHERE   TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,NOW(),`Time`) > 15
```

EDIT:

```
 Select `RecordID`, `CarNo`, `lat`, `lon` ,`Time` 
 From gps_gotaxiking 
 WHERE 
 RecordID IN (SELECT Max(`RecordID`) `RecordID` FROM gps_gotaxiking
        group by CarNo )

 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,NOW(),`Time`) > 15
```

Comment: if i want to add time condition like Time > NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE, how can i add the condition into the sql?

Comment: you have time column ?

Comment: i have time column in my table which name is `Time`, and i execute your edited answer cannot run. please look my edited question, thx.

Comment: i dont know if you want < 15 or > 15 , you have to make what you want.